# How to calculate a mismatch score between n number of strings more efficiently?

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, time-complexity

Suppose I have a vector that contains `n` strings, where the strings can be length 5...n. Each string must be compared with each string character by character. If there is a mismatch, the score is increased by one. If there is a match, the score does not increase. Then I will store the resulting scores in a matrix.

I have implemented this in the following way:

```
for (auto i = 0u; i < vector.size(); ++i)
{
  // vector.size() x vector.size() matrix
  std::string first = vector[i]; //horrible naming convention
  for (auto j = 0u; j < vector.size(); ++j)
  {
    std::string next = vector[j];
    int score = 0;
    for (auto k = 0u; k < sizeOfStrings; ++k)
    {
      if(first[k] == second[k])
      {
        score += 0;
      }
      else
      {
        score += 1;
      }
    }
    //store score into matrix
  }
}
```

I am not happy with this solution because it is `O(n^3)`. So I have been trying to think of other ways to make this more efficient. I have thought about writing another function that would replace the innards of our `j` for loop, however, that would still be `O(n^3)` since the function would still need a `k` loop.

I have also thought about a queue, since I only care about `string[0]` compared to `string[1]` to `string[n]`. `String[1]` compared to `string[2]` to `string[n]`. `String[2]` compared to `string[3]` to `string[n]`, etc. So my solutions have unnecessary computations since each string is comparing to every other string. The problem with this, is I am not really sure how to build my matrix out of this.

I have finally, looked into the std template library, however `std::mismatch` doesn't seem to be what I am looking for, or `std::find`. What other ideas do you guys have?

Comment: If performance is the issue, then I suggest first making sure your current algorithm has a chance to perform well i.e. use references rather than copying strings everywhere: `std::string& next = vector[j];`

Comment: @keith, I currently have this in a function where the vectors are passed in by reference, but I did not think to pass the string by reference. I am just trying to get away from `O(n^3)` comparisons. This just seems like a classic dynamic programming question.

Comment: (1) : converts your vector of strings into a matrix m where m[n] is the list of #occurences of each char found at position #n in the strings: `{"aaa"},{"abb"},{"abc"}` -> `{{3},{2,1},{1,1,1}}`.

Comment: (2) realize that the total score is the sum of the score of each `m[n]`.

Comment: (3) realize the score of `m[n]` is easy to compute with a bit of combinatory.

Comment: (4) enjoy.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can easily get away from O(n^3) comparisons, but you can easily implement the change you talk about.  Since the comparisons only need to be done one way (i.e. comparing string[1] to string[2] is the same as comparing string[2] to string[1]), as you point out, you don't need to iterate through the entire array each time and can change the start value of your inner loop to be the current index of your outer loop:

```
for (auto i = 0u; i < vector.size(); ++i) {
    // vector.size() x vector.size() matrix
    std::string first = vector[i]; //horrible naming convention
    for (auto j = i; j < vector.size(); ++j) {
```

To store it in a matrix, setup your `i` x `j` matrix, initialize it to all zeroes and simply store each score in `M[i][j]`

```
for (auto k = 0u; k < sizeOfStrings; ++k) {
    if (first[k] != second[k]) {
        M[i][j]++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not think to do it that way. Why do you think there is no easy way of getting around `n^3` comparisons?

Comment: Well, if you were comparing just string equality, you could probably do better (by sorting the list, or using a hashtable), but you are actually counting the number of differences between each pair of strings.  To see how many differences there are between 2 strings, you must compare the entire strings, O(n), and you must compare each string with each other string, O(n^2).

Comment: Also note that` O(n^3)` does not mean you have to do that many comparisons, it just means that your comparisons will grow at the same rate as `n^3` as `n` increases.  By changing `j` to start at the current value of `i`, you actually halve the number of comparisons you do, but it is still considered `O(n^3)`, constant factors are not applied when describing the complexity.

Answer (score 1):

If you have n strings each of length m, then no matter what (even with your queue idea), you have to do at least (n-1)+(n-2)+...+(1)=n(n-1)/2 string comparisons, so you'll have to do (n(n-1)/2)*m char comparisons. So no matter what, your algorithm is going to be O(mn^2).

Comment: This is not necessarily true. It may be possible to reformulate the problem to avoid having to perform all those comparisons. For example by utilizing that if string A and B agree in position k, then B also agrees with all other strings that agree with A in that position. However, Helium_1s2's answer should be taken as an indication that the problem can't be simplified without a major change to the structure of the algorithm.

Comment: I agree with @KristoferBjörnson, this just seems like a classic application to use Dynamic Programming in. The results in the matrix would be symmetric. Meaning I am computing results that I already know that I have. But Kristofer, how drastic would the change be?

Comment: @Sailanarmo Stephen Docy already gave a solution that roughly would cut the time in half by using symmetric property of the equality sign. This does not change the scaling behavior, but is significant.

What I suggest is that the scaling behavior itself maybe can be changed using the transitive property of the equality sign. However, I do not have a concrete suggestion in mind right now and I do not know to what degree the situation can be improved.

Answer (score 1):

- General comment:

You don't have to compare the same strings with each other. And what is more important you starting from the begining each time in second loop while you already computed those diffs, so change the second loop to start from `i+1`.
By doing so your complexity will decrease as you won't check string that you already checked or are the same.

- Improvement

Sort vector and remove duplicated entries, then instead wasting computation for checking the same strings you will only check those that are different.

Comment: Will sorting not throw off the order of my matrix? For example, string["abc"], string["aab"], and string["aaa"]. The comparison between string["abc"] and string["aab"] would need to go into Matrix[0,1]. However, if I sort them, string["aaa"], string["aab"], string["abc"], that would throw off the number would it not?

Answer (score 1):

The other answers that say this is at least O(mn^2) or O(n^3) are incorrect.  This can be done in O(mn) time where m is string size and n is number of strings.

For simplicity we'll start with the assumption that all characters are ascii.

You have a data structure:

```
int counts[m][255]
```

where counts[x][y] is the number of strings that have ascii character y at index x in the string.

Now, if you did not restrict to ascii, then you would need to use a std::map

```
map counts[m]
```

But it works the same way, at index m in counts you have a map in which each entry in the map y,z tells you how many strings z use character y at index m.  You would also want to choose a map with constant time lookups and constant time insertions to match the complexity.

Going back to ascii and the array

```
int counts[m][255] // start by initializing this array to all zeros
```

First initialize the data structure:

m is size of strings, 
vec is a std::vector with the strings

```
for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
    std::string str = vec[i];
    for(int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        counts[j][str[j]]++;
    }
}
```

Now that you have this structure, you can calculate the scores easily:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
    std::string str = vec[i];
    int score = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            score += counts[j][str[j]] - 1; //subtracting 1 gives how many other strings have that same char at that index
    }
    std::cout << "string \"" << str << "\" has score " << score;
}
```

As you can see by this code, this is O(m * n)

Comment: I had a feeling there was a solution similar to this as this felt this was a classic dynamic programming question. But can I ask, what was your thought process going through this? All I kept thinking was, “I am computing values I already know.” But I didn’t know how to get to the next step.

Comment: Well, I guess the thought process is that for each character in your string, you don't need to keep on checking every string for the same character, you just need to know how many other strings have that character.  How many other strings having that character is something you can calculate up front.  So in problems like these, look for things that do not need to be repeated.  In this case you don't need to repeat the process of going through every other string to look for a given character.  In general try to identify those things that need not be repeated, calculate once and reuse.